# Angular Material button-toggle-group not update input multiple

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a `mat-button-toggle-group` component that by default comes with `selectMultipleHoras` equal to false, I need to update the multiple input through a variable that I change at some point.

When I change the value of the `selectMultipleHoras` variable to true, my component input does not update with the new value so that I can select multiples.

**component.ts**

```
  public selectMultipleHours = false;

  public onBloqueadoChange(event): void {
    this.selectMultipleHours = false;
    if (event.checked) {
      this.selectMultipleHours = true;
    }
  }
```

**component.html**

```
      <mat-button-toggle-group color="accent" [formControl]="hourCtrl"
                        *ngIf="(hours| async).length > 0" [multiple]="selectMultipleHours"
                        #groupHoras="matButtonToggleGroup" fxLayout="row wrap" fusePerfectScrollbar>
                        <mat-button-toggle color="accent" *ngFor="let v of hours| async" [value]="v"
                            aria-label="Text align left">
                            <small>{{ v.hour }}</small>
                        </mat-button-toggle>
      </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Comment: in your html you are using `[multiple]="selectMultipleHours"` and in your ts file your are using `selectMultipleHoras` isnt it type error ?

Comment: sorry but that's not the problem, my code is the same name, I made a mistake here when posting.